# @GeneratedValue Annotation, Constructor value

Tags: java, hibernate, jaxb, annotations, jax-rs

I can not seem to find any documentaion on how to use the GeneratedValue annotation when it comes to initialising my object.

here is my id field for my object class, I have two other fields which I have left out

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ID")
private BigDecimal id;
```

my constructors

```
public Pothole() {
}

public Pothole(BigDecimal id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Pothole(BigDecimal id, byte[] image, Date pdate) {
    this.id = id;
    this.image = image;
    this.pdate = pdate;
}
```

What do I use for my id field?? Do I leave it empty

```
Pothole entity = new Pothole(???,decodedBytes, date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should leave it empty and when Hibernate will persist the entity in the database (ie, perform an `insert` statement), the `id` of the given entity will be valued by the database (in your case, the id column will provide the value).
The ìd` attribute will remain empty until the entity is persisted.

Answer (score 0):

using the default constructor worked

```
 Pothole entity = new Pothole();
    entity.setImage(decodedBytes);
    entity.setPdate(date);
```